# TeamCity:Version Control System User Name settings

Tags: svn, version-control, teamcity

how to add a new Version Control System (VCS)username in team city?

because as i am a build owner ,i have set my username in the team city login and username for the subversion as same.

so is that any prerequisite i need to take care while adding new Version Control system username?

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure VCS roots](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Roots) with whatever username/password you choose.  Some roots, such as SVN and Git, even allow you to use SSH keys.

You can not, however, use TeamCity to create a new SVN user.  That must be done at the SVN server.

**EDIT:** You can test the connection to SVN by clicking the `Test Connection` button at the bottom of the `Edit VCS Root` screen.  If this indicates that the connection is successful, then you've set up your VCS authentication properly.

Comment: thanks for your reply... i configured the vcs roots but my teamcity is not triggering the build even though i configured vcs trigger....

Comment: and one more thing it is not showing any changes in the 'My Changes' Tab.

Comment: Please see my edit.  It provides a method for verifying that you VCS authentication is properly configured.